# How to stop getting null on my arrayList

Tags: java

For this code I am supposed to read in a file and make it into an `ArrayList`. I keep getting half of my `ArrayList`, and the other half comes up as what I declared the variable to be.

The code is supposed to be running through another class, which is extended.

```
public static void inputDoctorRecords(ArrayList<Person> doc) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //opening file
    Scanner console = new Scanner(new File("Doctor.dat"));

    Doctor dr;
    String lastName = null;
    String firstName = null;
    String Street = null;
    String City = null;
    String State = null;
    String Zip = null;
    int Ident = 0;
    String loc = null;
    double sal = 0.0;
    String Spec = null;
    boolean done = true;
    boolean fin = true;
    String sys = null;

    while(console.hasNext() ){
        String names = console.next();
        dr = new Doctor(lastName, firstName, Street,State, City, Zip, Ident, loc, sal, Spec);

        if (names.equals("LName")){
            lastName = console.next();
        }
        if(names.equals("FName")){
            firstName = console.next();
        }
        if (names.equals("Street")){
            Street = console.nextLine();
        }
        if (names.equals("City")){
            City = console.nextLine();
        }
        if (names.equals("State")){
            State = console.next();
        }
        if (names.equals("Zip")){
            Zip = console.next();
        }
        if (names.equals("Ident")){
            Ident = console.nextInt();               
        }
        if (names.equals("Loc")){ //returns null
            loc = console.next();
        }
        if (names.equals("Salary")){ // returns 0.0
            sal = console.nextDouble();
        }
        if (names.equals("Spec")){ // returns null
            Spec = console.next();
        }
        if (names.equals("next")){ // goes to the next person in file
            doc.remove(dr);
            doc.add(dr);  
        }           
    }
    dr = new Doctor(lastName, firstName, Street,State, City, Zip, Ident, loc, sal, Spec);

    doc.remove(dr);
    doc.add( dr);
    System.out.println( doc);  
}
```

```
// here is the input file
            LName   Builder
           FName    Robert
           DOByy    1985
      DOBmm 12
 DOBdd  31
Ident   123456
Loc Seattle
Spec    Cardiology
Salary  100000.0
Street  123 Mockingjay
City    Sector 12
State   WA
Zip 98058
next
LName   Builder
FName   Roberta
DOByy   1988
DOBmm   11
DOBdd   22
Ident   234567
Loc Fife
Spec    Oncology
Salary  120000.0
Street  123 Mockingjay
City    Sector 12
State   WA
Zip 98058
next
LName   Klein
DOByy   1974
DOBdd   06
Loc Tacoma
Street  59 West Rodeo Drive
Ident   345678
City    Hollywood
DOBmm   05
State   CA
FName   Calvin
Zip 90210
Spec    Dermatology
Salary  150000.0
eof
```

Comment: you don't show where you declare and initialize your list, so my guess ... initialize it. also: make your code more efficient.
for instance, if you have this: if (names.equals("Salary")){ 
                sal = console.nextDouble();
            } if (names.equals("Spec")){  Spec = console.next(); }

replace it by: if (names.equals("Salary")){ sal = console.nextDouble(); }
            else if (names.equals("Spec")){ Spec = console.next();}
since it is not possible for both to be true. also, check what those methods do if you don't understand the results.

Comment: Please also provide an example input file, that can help to better understand the problem...

Comment: The problem is you have to check before each next if `hasNext`.  That means you should change all your `if` with a `switch` or `if`/`else`

Comment: You create a new `Doctor` in every iteration of the loop. That isn't really necessary. You only need to create the `Doctor` just before calling `remove`/`add`. "Throwing away" about 10 of 11 `Doctor`s reduces the performance of your programm.

Comment: Wouldn't this duplicate information? Eg: If the first doctor gives his first name, and the rest of the doctors don't, then all doctors would have the same first name?

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner reads from InputStreams line by line, when you say for example `Zip = console.next();`, it discards everything it got from the current line. I recommend splitting the String using String#split().

**EDIT:** Scanner#next() consumes the string. Thats the word I was looking for.

Comment: If that answered your question, please accept the answer. If not, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
public static void inputDoctorRecords(ArrayList<Person> doc) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //opening file

    Scanner console = new Scanner(new File("Doctor.dat"));

    Doctor dr;
    String lastName = null;
    String firstName = null;
    String Street = null;
    String City = null;
    String State = null;
    String Zip = null;
    int Ident = 0;
    String loc = null;
    double sal = 0.0;
    String Spec = null;
    boolean done = true;
    boolean fin = true;
    String sys = null;

    while(console.hasNext() ) {
        String names = console.next();

        if (names.equals("LName")) {
            lastName = console.next();
        }
        else if(names.equals("FName")) {
            firstName = console.next();
        }
        else if (names.equals("Street")) { 
            Street = console.nextLine();    
        }
        else if (names.equals("City")) {
            City = console.nextLine();
        }
        else if (names.equals("State")) {
            State = console.next();
        }
        else if (names.equals("Zip")) {
            Zip = console.next();
        }
        else if (names.equals("Ident")) {
            Ident = console.nextInt();               
        }
        else if (names.equals("Loc")) {
            loc = console.next();   
        }
        else if (names.equals("Salary")) {
            sal = console.nextDouble();
        }
        else if (names.equals("Spec")) {
            Spec = console.next();
        }
        else if (names.equals("next")) { // goes to the next person in file
            dr = new Doctor(lastName, firstName, Street,State, City, Zip, Ident, loc, sal, Spec);
            doc.add(dr);      
        }  
        else {
            console.nextLine(); // ignore the line because it is unknown
        }
    }
    // Last Line
    dr = new Doctor(lastName, firstName, Street,State, City, Zip, Ident, loc, sal, Spec);    
    doc.add(dr);
    System.out.println(doc);  
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks! but I get the error :Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at Clinic.inputDoctorRecords(Clinic.java:185)
 at Clinic.main(Clinic.java:34)

Comment: I don't have all your code to know what specific line is causing that exception.  Do you know which line is causing the exception? Try removing the `else {
            console.nextLine();
        }`